# Proper fields for webpack production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I initially ran into a problem, where while in production, it takes the browsser 48.6s to download the index.bundle file. So the initial launch of the app is very slow but from there on it's smooth and quick.

Eventually, I figured it out that this is due to my webpack config trying to minify all the dependancies and such.

I'm trying to configure webpack correctly for a production build and I'm looking for some help. What tags am I missing or which options are set wrongly?

Versions:

- "webpack": "^3.5.3",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"

---

`npm run build` runs the `webpack -p --progress` command.

My webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].fonts.css');
const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].styles.css');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

console.log('BUILD_DIR', BUILD_DIR);
console.log('SRC_DIR', SRC_DIR);

module.exports = {
 devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    index: [SRC_DIR + '/index.js', require.resolve('whatwg-fetch')]
    },
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  watch: !!process.env.WATCH,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3333,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            presets: ['react', 'env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ['css-hot-loader'].concat(extractSCSS.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: { alias: { '../img': '../public/img' } }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        }))
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // loader: 'url-loader'
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: './img/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: './fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        }
      }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
     }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      mangle: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false, // Suppress uglification warnings
        pure_getters: true,
        unsafe: true,
        unsafe_comps: true,
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
      exclude: [/\.min\.js$/gi] // skip pre-minified libs
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    extractCSS,
    extractSCSS,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
      {
        inject: true,
        template: './public/index.html'
      }
    ),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: './public/img', to: 'img'}
      ],
      {copyUnmodified: false}
    )
  ]
}
;
```

Comment: You're going to want to look into [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) and code splitting. [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/courses/build-a-server-rendered-code-split-app-in-react-with-react-universal-component?utm_source=drip&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=eoy2017&utm_term=react&utm_content=ssr-react) has a great tutorial on code splitting using [React Universal Component](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component).

Comment: Thank you Kyle, but i was able to solve it myself with just hiding the dev env settings and keep source-map to false.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem!